# How to match a string

Tags: tcl

I have a string with the following entries:

```
test:form/gt_check
test:form/lt_check
```

I want a section of code to be executed once the string matches

```
test:form/gt_check
```

How can I do this with an if loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`string match`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35)?

```
set s "test:form/gt_check test:form/lt_check"
if {[string match {*test:form/gt_check*} $s]} {
    puts Yay!
}
```

Or a regular expression?

```
regexp {\mtest:form/gt_check\M} $s
```

(`\m` matches the beginning of a word, `\M` the end of one)

Or if your string is also a proper tcl list (As is the case with your example, at least), `in` in the `if`'s `expr`ression?

```
if {"test:form/gt_check" in $s} {
    puts Yay!
}
```